# Check if input of contenteditable div is numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contenteditable div that is to be used to input numeric values. If the value entered is not numeric, I want a message to alert saying that the value is not valid.

html:

```
<div class="myinput" contenteditable></div>
```

JS:

```
    if (myinput is not a number)
        alert("Please enter a valid number.");
```

What do I replace "myinput is not a number" with to get what I want? I tried using !$("div.number").html() but that only checks to see if any input exists, not a numeric one. I am not sure if it is possibile to use .isNumeric() after .html(). I must also keep the input as a div, I cannot use an input type="number". Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isNaN` :

```
if (isNaN($("div.number").html()))
```

Note that this also accepts strings with spaces at end (which is probably your case).

To get the number after that, the simplest solution is

```
var n = +$("div.number").html();
```